# Can python's OrderDict have decimals in keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

```
for k, pip in enumerate(tmp):
    pip = round(pip, 4)
    if pip in levels:
        print str(pip) + ' is already in list!'
        levels[pip] = (levels[pip] + int(round(percentiles[k]))) / 2.
    else:
        levels[pip] = int(round(percentiles[k]))
```

The pips are up to 4 decimals, e.g. 1.2345. Levels is an OrderDict

The `if` never evaluates to true; the values are always assigned (and overwritten). So how must I handle the keys?

Also, is there a more pythonic way to do this? Can't I zip the `percentiles` somehow with `tmp`?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the `OrderedDict` class from the standard library.  There shouldn't be any issue with using floats as `OrderedDict` keys.  Can you show a complete example that other people can run?

Comment: Do you mean `Decimal`s? Or `float`s? You mention `zip`, but have you actually tried it? What are you trying to achieve; why `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Note that using floats as dict keys has the same issues as comparing floats for equality; unless you're intimately familiar with floating point rounding behavior, you're probably not going to get exact matches, which means it's probably not going to work.

Comment: What does `levels.keys()` print?

Comment: @user2357112: The `round` *should* work to canonicalise things, though; it's a correctly-rounded operation in Python 2.7 (in the sense that it *will* return the closest representable double to the decimal rounded result).  That's not to say that this is the right way to do things, but I don't understand why the original code wouldn't work.  Unless the OP is using Python 2.6 (where `round` is not guaranteed to be correctly rounded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> d
OrderedDict([(1, 2)])
>>> d[1.234] = 4
>>> d
OrderedDict([(1, 2), (1.234, 4)])
>>> d[1.234]
4
>>> d[round(1.2343, 3)]
4
```

Yes, `OrderedDict`s can have floats as keys. The issue you're seeing is because of something else -- are you expecting `levels` to be populated before the loop here? Or should you have multiple values in the loop that round to the same value?

I modified your code quickly to test it, and everything works out. Can you provide some data that results in the bug you're seeing?

```
>>> cache = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for index, value in enumerate([1.234, 2.345, 1.234]):
...     rounded_value = round(value, 2)
...     if rounded_value in cache:
...             print("we already found {0}!".format(rounded_value))
...     else:
...             print("{0} is new".format(rounded_value))
...             cache[rounded_value] = index
... 
1.23 is new
2.35 is new
we already found 1.23!
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
from odict import odict
levels=odict()
tmp=[1.01234,1.13333,1.233333,1.13333]
percentiles=[3.2,1,3,3]
for k, pip in enumerate(tmp):
    pip = round(pip, 4)
    if pip in levels:
       print str(pip) + ' is already in list!'
       #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
       levels[pip] = (levels[pip] + int(round(percentiles[k]))) / 2.
    else:
        levels[pip] = int(round(percentiles[k]))
```